# What is the best approach for storing simple Information in contact us and about us pages?Databases or Files

Tags: php, database, wordpress

In **Contact us** and **About us** pages in websites some information (For example Address , email , phone and etc) are simple and short, But some Customers want can access them and change dynamically in their Admin panel while developers prefer those were be Static.

[image]

However My question is when these information must be Dynamic, what is best approach to Storing them?

Do we must to use Database tables that only have one record (that have easy inserting and fetching) or we must to use files to store then while working with files and change them is hard and time consuming.

which approach is better and usual in modern Systems like Wordpress and other CMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database is the most common because it allows for easy searching and supports complex querying. Databases such as mysql and postgres are also relatively easy to access and update relative to a file system.

In short, both are possible, but a database is the most common approach, and provides many more features and options for future functionality.

Comment: using Database Tables is effective really ? means create two separate tables for contact_us and about_us information Each with a row?

Comment: No, 1 table will do. A table with fields for page name and for the content.

Comment: I think that you have Supposed this, when entire about us and  us page content can change by Admin, but i want to design a static template and admin can change about us and contact us informations separately via a simple form in her panel. in this case we must have two separate tables with fields same name that information have.Right?

Comment: When displaying or editing the about us page you would use SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_type = 'about-us'

Answer (score 1):

Storing data in `Database` is the best option due to simplicity, maintainability and easy to access.

Storing in `FILE` is not recommended because if you want to get selected user details you will have to read the entire file. Also updating details will be tedious. In case of `Database` it can be very easily fetched / updated by a simple query.

So for simplicity and ease go for `Database`.